# chunky_png NoMethodError

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to create a sprite with compass, but I keep getting this error:

```
NoMethodError on line ["225"] of /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/chunky_png-1.2.7/lib/chunky_png/canvas/png_encoding.rb: undefined method `downto' for 150.25:Float
```

I have tried everything including using previous version of chunky_png and reinstalling compass and sass.

Would love to know how to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  I just had to update all of my ruby gems and then restart my computer.  I have had no problems since.